# Is `timescale a preprocessor instruction?

Tags: verilog

All Verilog lines of code that start with the character `` ` ``  seem to be preprocessor instructions. However `` `timescale `` seems to be an odd one out, maybe.

Is `` `timescale `` a preprocessor instruction? If it is, what is it replaced by?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Verilog, the backtick denotes a **compiler directive**.  These are evaluated when the Verilog source code is compiled.  `` `timescale `` sets the time unit and time precision for the modules which follow it in the source code.

`` `timescale `` does not do text macro substitution, as `` `define `` does.

Refer to the IEEE Standard (1800-2009, for example) for further details.